# Answers.OnStartups isn't "offline for maintenance", is it?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, closed-sites, answers-onstartups

If you visit http://answers.onstartups.com/ (which was formerly a beta site, and is [now closed](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6243/startup-business)), you get the following message:

> ## We are currently offline for maintenance
>
> This Stack Exchange site is temporarily offline, routine maintenance usually takes less than an hour.  If this turns into an extended outage you can follow the status **on the [status blog](https://www.stackstatus.net/)**.

This message, which is not accurate, also appears at http://meta.answers.onstartups.com/.

I suppose this might be something that is beyond the control of the folks at SE, given that Answers.OnStartups doesn't reside on an SE domain, but I figure it was worth noting, anyway.

Comment: It looks like the domain name points to an IP address that no longer supports the host name; what you see is a generic message when the load balancer doesn't have a site to serve for a given host.

Comment: These messages have been popping up across several sites I frequent.

Answer (score 1):

Looks about right to me now:

[image]